# Android Share Options Dialog

Tags: android

I need to make a dialog for share just like this. Is there any way to reuse the one that android already implements or do I have to build it "from scratch"? I am thinking about use a gridView and implement an adapter for the icons views, but before I want to make sure that there is no way to reuse the exiting one.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are various ways of sharing in Android, using the `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` Intent.

Here are two to get you started :)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

and

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

The first one is more what you're after, but in case you wanted a slightly more subtle button, the second one will do that quite nicely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemeted at Android:

```
final Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    final String text = ctx.getString(R.string.text_share);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                    ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, item));
```